# Livedata is working on one activity but not working on other activity

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I was loading a list of animal information from SQLite database. I've used MVVM architecture. I've two-button that in my `MainActivity` and starts two different activities. One is `AnimalAugmented` other is `AnimalIntroducer`. In both activities, I load the same data. For loading data in `AnimalAugmented` I've used written following code

```java
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_animals);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        AnimalAdapter animalAdapter = new AnimalAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(animalAdapter);

        animalViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AnimalViewModel.class);
        animalViewModel.getAllAnimals().observe(this, animals -> {
            animalAdapter.setAnimals(animals);
        });
```

It works fine. But when I try to load data in `AnimalIntroducer` it doesn't show any item. For `AnimalIntroducer` I've used previous code

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animal_introducer);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_animal_introducer);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        AnimalAdapter animalAdapter = new AnimalAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(animalAdapter);

        animalViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AnimalViewModel.class);
        animalViewModel.getAllAnimals().observe(this, animals -> {

            animalAdapter.setAnimals(animals);
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: grid "+animals.size());
            for(Animal animal:animals){
                Log.e(TAG,animal.getBanglaName());
            }
        });
    }
```

Here it prints the size of the animal list in log as expected but doesn't show any item. But If I load data from an ArrayList instead of ViewModel it works. So why my activity is not showing any item from SQLite?

```java
        animalAdapter.setAnimals(AnimalDump.insertToList());
```

Here is my `AnimalAdapter` class

```java
public class AnimalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "Augmented";
    private static final int TYPE_FREE = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_LOCKED = 2;
    List<Animal> animals= new ArrayList<>();

    public OnItemClickListener listener;

    public AnimalAdapter() {

        Log.d(TAG, "AnimalAdapter: ");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        if(viewType==TYPE_FREE){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_animal,parent,false);
            return new AnimalViewHolder(view);
        }
        else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_animal_locked,parent,false);
            return new LockedAnimalViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Animal animal=animals.get(position);
        if(animal.isOffline()){
            ((AnimalViewHolder)holder).setValues(animal);
        }
        else {
            ((LockedAnimalViewHolder)holder).setValues(animal);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return animals.size();
    }

    public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
        Log.d(TAG, "setAnimals: ");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(animals.get(position).isOffline())
            return TYPE_FREE;
        else
            return TYPE_LOCKED;
    }

    public void setListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected class AnimalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView itemAnimalImageView;
        private TextView itemAnimalTextView;
        private Context context;
        public CardView itemCardView;

        public AnimalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemAnimalImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_animal_image_view);
            itemAnimalTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_animal_text_view);
            itemCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card_view);
            context = itemView.getContext();

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(listener!=null && position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    listener.onItemClick(animals.get(position));
                }

                YoYo.with(Techniques.RollIn)
                        .duration(700)
                        .repeat(0)
                        .playOn(itemAnimalImageView);

            });

        }

        public void setValues(Animal animal){
            itemAnimalTextView.setText(animal.getBanglaName());
            itemAnimalImageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(animal.getId(),"drawable",context.getPackageName()));
        }
    }

    protected class LockedAnimalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView itemAnimalImageView,itemLockIcon;
        private TextView itemAnimalTextView;
        private Context context;
        public CardView itemCardView;

        public LockedAnimalViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemAnimalImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_animal_image_view);
            itemAnimalTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_animal_text_view);
            itemCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card_view);
            itemLockIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_lock);
            context = itemView.getContext();

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                YoYo.with(Techniques.RubberBand)
                        .duration(700)
                        .repeat(0)
                        .playOn(itemAnimalImageView);

            });

        }

        public void setValues(Animal animal){
            itemAnimalTextView.setText(animal.getBanglaName());
            itemAnimalImageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(animal.getId(),"drawable",context.getPackageName()));
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Animal animal);
    }
```

Comment: Post `AnimalAdapter`  class code

Comment: @MD I've added `AnimalAdapter` class. Please check. I've used same AnimalAdapter class for both activities.

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChaged()` inside `setAnimals(..)` after `this.animals = animals;`

Comment: @MD Thanks a lot... It worked. Post it in the answer section so I can give a checkmark :v btw why it was working on `AnimalAugmented` I don't get it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `notifyDataSetChaged()` inside `setAnimals(..)` after `this.animals = animals;`

You must call `notifyDataSetChaged()` after your list data changed

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView Adapters require you to inform them about any changes in the dataset. Obviously, the adapter can not magically know, you added an item to the list. So at least, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which will simply invalidate all items and render them again.

In your case, you would probably want to add this to your `setAnimals` method:

```java
public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // << this is important
    Log.d(TAG, "setAnimals: ");
}
```